# rm is not working and outputs mv: illegal option -- b

Tags: command-line-interface, zsh, oh-my-zsh, iterm2, macos-monterey

I'm using Monterey and ohmyzsh in iterm2 and rm -rf (nor -Rf) is not working and outputs mv: illegal option -- b. What is a good cli way to do this?

Edit: I have used remove in the past to remove files on a MBP. I believe it implicitly calls mv to do the work under the hood. This has since stopped functioning since my last project I have worked on in the past few months. It may have to do with sudo permissions (I dunno), Monterey, or it may possibly have to do with oh-my-zsh. At this point I was just looking for direction to look for an answer to look towards.

Comment: Maybe `rm` is not what you think it is. What does `type rm` say? Another possibility would be that you have defined a _precmd_ which gets in your way.

Comment: BTW, what happens if you type `command rm -rf YOUR_DIRECTORY` or `/usr/bin/rm -rf YOUR_DIRECTORY` instead?

Comment: zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/bin/rm is outputted when trying to do a /usr/bin/rm. I wonder if something is aliased incorrectly for rm, but don't remember how to check it. It may be a relearn. command rm -rf worked. Not sure why that is the new way to do this, do you?

Comment: Well, then you have your `rm` in a different directory, say `usr/local/bin` or wherever. But if `command rm ...` works, it means that you have a function of alias named `rm` (and `type rm` will show you what it is).

Comment: Is there a way to see what is aliasing what? Oh-my-zsh, Monterety, and my own hacked up ...rc files?

Comment: I don't think that you can find easily which file has defined your alias. If it is a function, `type` should show it. For an alias, you probably have to grep for it.

Answer (score 0):

After editing my original question I am coming back to post that command `rm -rf file_to_delete` works today. It would be nice to know where we could find documentation that explains this.

Comment: Upon inspection of my .zshrc file I was attempting to prevent accident clobbering of data and directories with a function which is creating the confusion. ```rm () {
    mkdir -p "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/recycle_bin" &&
    mv -b -- "$@" "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/recycle_bin"
}```